# div inside button not responding to heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/VSvHE/1/)

I am making a social thumbs up button, and I'm having some issues. Inside my full button I have a second `div` to hold the right side of it. But it is about `15px` tall, even if I use CSS to make it `300px` tall. It also won't size with width. It is about `10px` away from the right edge of the button container.

Comment: Try using div instead of a button

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to expand with whatever content you put in it, then the height property can't be set to an absolute value. Remove this line:

```
height: 25px;
```

from the #b CSS class and your button element should expand to contain whatever content you want inside of it. An alternative to the height property is the min-height property so instead of deleting the above line of css you could replace it with:

```
min-height: 25px;
```

The same principle applies with the CSS `width` property.